# Compress files with django_compressor to gzip

Tags: django, django-templates, gzip, django-compressor

I use [django_compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#backend-settings) to compress my js and css files. It creates combined files successfully. But this app also allow to zip files. To enable this I created

```
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'compressor.storage.GzipCompressorFileStorage'
```

in my settings.py. In compressor work dir there are now gzip files for css and js. But after checking html with firebug it looks like gzip files are not during rendering process. How can I change it?

Comment: Are you in development or production (`DEBUG=True` or `DEBUG=False`)? django-compressor disables most of its actual machinery in development for obvious reasons, so it's likely this too will only work in production.

Comment: Here's the setting for it: http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED

Comment: @Chris Pratt: I will check with debug true/false.

Comment: @pastylegs: I have COMPRESS_ENABLED set to true already. I is now what I am looking for.

Comment: @Chris Pratt: That`s the solution :) Please add comment as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

django-compressor disables most of its actual machinery in development (`DEBUG=True`) for obvious reasons, so it's likely this too will only work in production.